# Metro Apps crashing Windows 8 - corrupt windows files?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store-app

I have Windows 8. (Not 8.1)

Metro apps won't open, i.e. Mail, Photos, Weather, Games, Sport, Bing, Travel, Skype...

Windows Store works until installing an app, to which I get the error message "Something happened and the windows store is no longer working, please restart/refresh windows on your PC"

I have tried typing "SFC /scannow" in the command line but I get the error that it contains corrupt files it cannot fix.

I have tried the ordinary Windows metro apps troubleshooter and it explains that either the display adapters are out of date (I have updated them) or Windows Store Configuration may be damaged. That may narrow down the problem.

I have tried running the command - "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackageDisableDevelopmentMode Register$Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML" but get the following error message - "Deployment failed, the package repository is corrupted".

Also, it seems that registries have full permissions to ALL APP PACKAGES so that's not an issue either.

Hopefully there is enough information above to identify the problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Use DISM to repair the WiNSXS contents so you can use SFC or use a installation disk as the source for SFC

Comment: If you install 8.1 the corruption will also be repaired

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. In my case, I had stupidly changed the permissions on the entire "App Data" folder, which somehow removed the permission that was needed for some Windows Metro apps. It seems that every Package has its own permissions set. After some research, and following the same fix attempts you described (which also did not work for me) the following fix did eventually work:

Add a user called ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to the Packages folder and all its children.

Detailed steps (for anyone less familiar with Windows):

1. Go to C:/Users/[your username]/App Data/Local. There should be a folder there called Packages.
2. Right Click and choose Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add
3. Type in "ALL" and then click on "Check Names". This should autofill the filed with a user called ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES. Choose it and give it Full Control.
4. Click OK.
5. Click OK. You should be back in the Packages Properties window.
6. Click "Advanced".
7. Check the box next to "Replace all child object permission entries...."
8. Click Apply.